# AngularJS ng-repeat different formatting

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have JSON like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "parent1",
    "children":
    [
      {
        "name": "child1",
        "foo": "bar"
      },
      {
        "name": "child2",
        "foo": "bar"
      },
      {
        "name": "child2",
        "foo": "bar"
      },
      {
        "name": "child3",
        "foo": "bar"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "parent2",
    "children":
    [
      {
        "name": "child1",
        "foo": "bar"
      },
      {
        "name": "child2",
        "foo": "bar"
      },
      {
        "name": "child2",
        "foo": "bar"
      },
      {
        "name": "child3",
        "foo": "bar"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And I want to use ng-repeat to render a `<select>` list as following:

```
<select>
    <option disabled>parent1</option>
    <option>child1</option>
    <option>child2</option>
    <option>child3</option>
    <option>child4</option>
    <option disabled>parent2</option>
    <option>child1</option>
    <option>child2</option>
    <option>child3</option>
    <option>child4</option>
</select>
```

However, I can't seem to get this to work. In a different topic on Stackoverflow I saw the same issue, however this was just with regular div, and one div wrapping around the parent/children, so you can easily repeat on that div. However, its not possible here. I've tried to wrap divs and other elements around each 'family', but 1) its terrible code, and 2) its not even working.

Comment: It would probably be most simple to just flatten out the array to a single level in your controller. Or for something more self-contained, a custom directive would do it (the custom directive would do the array-flattening internally). But to do it alone with ng-repeat is (as far as I know) not possible.

Comment: Can you provide me any references to flatten this out? That would indeed be a good solution.

Comment: Yes, I'll construct a simple demo and post it as an answer shortly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method you could use to flatten out the source json into a flat format that is easy to use in an ng-repeat, or ng-repeat-like directive such as the ng-options:

```
$scope.options = []; // this will store the flattened array
angular.forEach(response, function(group) {
    $scope.options.push({ name: group.name, isParent: true});

    angular.forEach(group.children, function(child) {
        $scope.options.push({ name: child.name, isParent: false});
    });
});
```

You'll end up with an array like this:

```
[
    {"name":"parent1","isParent":true},
    {"name":"child1","isParent":false},
    {"name":"child2","isParent":false},
    {"name":"child2","isParent":false},
    {"name":"child3","isParent":false},
    {"name":"parent2","isParent":true},
    {"name":"child1","isParent":false},
    {"name":"child2","isParent":false},
    {"name":"child2","isParent":false},
    {"name":"child3","isParent":false}
]
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/VpxGIhaLa2W1xxOTUnxv?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

With your json as $scope.nodes something like this should work

```
<select>
<option ng-repeat-start="node in nodes" disabled>{{node.name}}</option>
<option ng-repeat="child in node.children">{{child.name}}</option>
<option ng-repeat-end ng-show="false"></option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is a great solution, that should be considered over my answer since you don't need the extra code in your controller.

Comment: Nice answer. Can you please explain what's going wrong with `selectedChild` in this example http://jsfiddle.net/m09od0c5/6/

Comment: @hansmaad Setting the value of an option will set that value to a string, so what really happens is that your option values will be child.toString(), and not the actual object.

Answer (score 1):

### Controller:

```
var children = [];
angular.forEach(source, function(parent) {        
    angular.forEach(parent.children, function(child) {
        children.push({ name: child.name, parent: parent.name});
    });
});

$scope.children = children;

$scope.selectedChild = $scope.children[0];
```

### HTML

```
<select ng-model="selectedChild" 
        ng-options="child.name group by child.parent for child in children">
</select>
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m09od0c5/)

Comment: Obviously I need to use my default JSON source file. If you rewrite it, please show me how.

Comment: Firstly there was no need to downvote. Secondly you can convert your source json to something like the one shown above.

Comment: I don't want to argue with you, but obviously just changing the JSON source file is the easiest way, but thats not possible, and thats why I asked this question. Thanks for your input, and sorry if I didn't explain the issue properly enough.